# Ошибка при активации плагина

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, почему вылазит ошибка при активации плагина?

> Плагин произвёл при активации 372 символов неожиданного вывода. Если вы заметите ошибку «headers already sent», проблемы с RSS-лентами или другие неполадки, попробуйте деактивировать или удалить этот плагин.

код:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test
Version: 1.0
*/
// Запрещаем прямой доступ к файлу
if (!function_exists('add_action'))
    exit;

class Test{

    public $uploadDir;
    public $settings_group = 'test-settings-group';

    public function __construct() {
        $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
        $dir = $uploads['basedir'] . '/test';
        //        $this->uploadDir = $dir;
        $this->uploadDir = ABSPATH.'/wp-content/uploads/test';
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($this,'plugin_activate'));
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'register_settings'));
        add_action('init', array($this, 'wp_init'));
        $this->includes();
    }

    public function includes() {
        if ( ! defined( TEST_ABSPATH ) ) {
            define( TEST_ABSPATH, dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
        }
    }
    /**
     * Действия при активации плагина
     */
    public function plugin_activate(){

        if ( !is_dir($this->uploadDir)){
            wp_mkdir_p($this->uploadDir);
        }
    }
    public function wp_init() {

    }
    public function register_settings() {

    }
}

$plugin = new Test();
```

Comment: Какая-то ошибка в __construct, сообщение об ошибке и есть 372 символа.

Comment: @KAGG Design, так а что можно понять из этой ошибки ?
372 символа, это ни о чём не говорит.
Нужно искать в коде 372 неправильные символа?

Comment: в коде их нет. Еще раз - 372 символа - это длина сообщения об ошибке. А код надо отлаживать либо способами WordPress, либо отладчиками типа xdebug. Здесь всего-то несколько строчек, можно комментировать половину и смотреть, есть ли ошибка, потом половину из половины и т.д. А потом думать, почему найденная строка порождает ошибку, читать доки.